# Grails: Cannot invoke method sendEmail() on null object when using in service

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-plugin, grails-services

I have created a service `NotifierService`

```
class NotifierService {

    MailService mailService

    def sendEmail(String email) {
        mailService.sendMail {
            to email
            from "myemail@domain.com"
            subject "Subject"
            body "Some text"
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I'm trying to call `sendEmail` method in another method `updateUser` in `DbService` service

```
class DbService {
    NotifierService notifierService

    def updateUser(){
        //Some Logic
        //Get userObject

        def email = userObject.email

        //Send email
        try {
            notifierService.sendEmail(email)
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    //Other methods
    .
    .
    .
}
```

It works fine when I call `sendEmail` method in `BootStrap`, but I get the following error when I use it in `DbService`

```
| Error java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method sendMail() on null object
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:77)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:45)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:32)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
```

I understood that the `mailService` in `NotifierService` is not initialized when using it in `DbService`. How can I resolve it?

The `DbService` is instantiated in a grails-job

```
class MyJob {
    DbService dbService = new DbService()


    static triggers = {
        // start delay: 30000 (30sec), repeat: 120000 (2*60*1000 = 2min)
        simple name:'myJobTrigger', startDelay:30000, repeatInterval: 120000, repeatCount: -1
    }

    def execute() {
        println "*******************************************************"
        println "MyJob: "+new Date()
        println "*******************************************************"

        dbService.updateUser()
    }
}
```

Comment: how the `DbService` is instantiated?

Comment: I'm calling `DbService` methods in grails job using quartz plugin.

Comment: are both `NotifierService ` and `DbService` grails services?

Comment: Yes. I'll update the question with how `DbService` is instantiated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok, this is clear then :)

if you do

```
DbService dbService = new DbService()
```

then the dependencies will NEVER be populated with spring.

you have to leave it `un-initialized` so that the service is injected from the application context:

```
class MyJob {
  DbService dbService // or def dbService
}
```

Comment: Now I get `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method updateUser() on null object`

Comment: `DbService dbService  = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean 'dbService'` solved the problem.

Comment: the dependencies in quartz jobs should also be resolved `automagically`. If they are not, you must be doing something really wrong here or not following conventions...